# Detects no microphone when using Chrome browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

The code down bellow should detects the microphone. It works on all browser, but when i tested it on mac with latest google Chrome browser
the flash player initially detects that no microphone. But when i click on the "reload button" on the browser then it does detect the mic.

```
 var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();

    try {
     prompt.text ="mic.name "+mic.name;
        trace("mic.name "+mic.name)
    } catch (e:Error) {
         prompt.text ="no mic detected";
        trace("no mic detected")
    }
```

I heave searched google and spent many days trying to fix it... the only thing / way was to overcome this problem was to "reload" which is not that kind of fix we want.

Pleas help me out to fix it.. so it works like other browsers..